# Rotate Nexus 5 upside down?

Tags: auto-rotation

I have a Nexus that I'd like to set up on a stand while I have it plugged in.  To do this, I have to rotate the phone 180 degrees.  Unfortunately, Android on the phone does not seem to support this.  This works fine on my Nexus 7, but not on the Nexus 5.

Is there some setting that I can change to enable this?  The phone will do normal portrait, and landscape to either side, but it will not change the display to work when it is upside down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without a third-party application.

A quick [search on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rotation%20control&c=apps) shows several apps which should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I've tried a couple of those.  Unfortunately, they don't help.  They work for every direction except upside down.

Comment: I just tried Ultimate Rotation Control and that works all ways round, including upside down. It's a paid app but the free one has a 7 day trial.

Comment: I just tried it too, and it did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyKelsey By default yes, but there are apps that allow/enable full rotation on phones as indicated in my answer